# PrimeFaces autocomplete with omniFaces.ListConverter and ajax return null in backBean

Tags: ajax, primefaces, autocomplete

I'm trying to do a country/state/city loader with autocomplete tag but this don't works. I already had done with SelectOneMenu tag and it's works fine, but now I'm trying to implement it with autoComplete and I can't make it work properly because the method that is in the ajax tag returns null

this is my XHTML

```
<p:outputLabel value="Region"/>
<p:autoComplete value="#{beanPersona.region}"   completeMethod="#{beanPersona.listarRegion}"
                var="region" itemLabel="#{region.nombre}" itemValue="#{region}"
                forceSelection="true" autocomplete="true" dropdown="true" >
    <o:converter converterId="omnifaces.ListConverter" list="#{beanPersona.listRegion}"/>
    <p:ajax event="itemSelect" listener="#{beanPersona.onRegionChange}" process="@form"/>
</p:autoComplete>
```

and this is my Bean (Scoope is ViewScope and everithing else works fine)

```
public void onRegionChange(SelectEvent e) {
    System.out.println(e.getObject());
    this.region = (Region) e.getObject();
}

public List<Region> listarRegion(String filtro) {
    List<Region> listaCompleta = (List<Region>) (List<?>) new Dml().list(new Region());
    List<Region> lista = new ArrayList();
    if(filtro.length() > 0)
        for (Region objeto : listaCompleta) {
            if(objeto.getNombre().toLowerCase().contains(filtro.toLowerCase()))
                lista.add(objeto);
        }
    else
        lista = listaCompleta;
    return lista;
}
```

if you could help me I would appreciate it